# Can Fake of data in the header Origin (websocket)?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Can you falsify the header data in Origin?

```
GET /ttt HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: http://webru.ru
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 32f2f2f2342r23
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Comment: Congratulations !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a statement, not a question

Comment: I'm Ron Burgundy?

Comment: I knew that was you, too many things just didn't add up, like the weather obsession.

Comment: The question. You can fake the header data in Origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The contents of the `Origin` header are always set by the browser, and cannot be overridden.

Comment: I can use  for fake of data in the header Origin (websocket)?- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: I can use for fake of data in the header Origin (websocket)?- developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: But what if I use something other than a browser?